# PineScript: enter after x amount of bars

Tags: pine-script

So my code seems to be working fine, but when the condition is met twice it restarts the counter on the bars, leading to a missed opportunity for the intended entry.

I want an entry after x amount of bars after rsi has closed under 10, regardless of what rsi does before the x amount. The problem is if rsi crosses under 10, then crosses up, then crosses down again, it restarts the counter on the bars before the entry and that creates a problem.

```
rsi = ta.rsi(close, rsiLen)
isOB= ta.crossover(rsi, i_OB)
isOS= ta.crossunder(rsi, i_OS)
BarsSinceOB = ta.barssince(isOB)
BarsSinceOS = ta.barssince(isOS)

BUY = BarsSinceOS == i_delay 
ACT = direction < 0
strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when = ACT and BUY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a few variables and if conditions.

For the example, I set the rsi target to 50, instead of 10. As you can see in the screenshot, it will start counting when the rsi crosses under 50, and will ignore the rsi movement within 10 bars. 3 green arrows are where the rsi closses below 50.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

barDelay = 10
rsiTarget = 50
my_rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
rsi_cond = ta.crossunder(my_rsi, rsiTarget)

var barIdxAtCond = 0
var startCounting = false
startCounting := rsi_cond ? true : startCounting
barsElapsed = false

if (not startCounting[1] and startCounting)
    barIdxAtCond := bar_index
    
if (startCounting and ((bar_index - barIdxAtCond) > barDelay-1))
    startCounting := false
    barsElapsed := true

hline(rsiTarget, "H", color.red)
plot(my_rsi)
bgcolor(barsElapsed ? color.green : na)
```

[image]

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes! Thank you. Now if I may be a choosing nether, can you explain each line of code so I can use this as a learning opportunity?